# does ('filename','w') replace or add

Tags: python

If I had a file called 'file' that said

```
thing1

thing2
```

and I did

```
f = open('file','w')
f.write('hi'+'\n')
f.close()
```

would file become

```
thing1

thing2

hi
```

or

```
hi
```

edit : when testing this, i did a code saying

```
new_un = open('usernames', 'w')
for i in range(len(usernames)):
    new_un.write(usernames[i]+'\n')
new_un.close()
```

and it would write everything in the usernames list.
I thought that if it was overriding then it would just have the last thing in the list

Comment: The file would be overwritten. If you want to append to a file, use `'a'` instead of `'w'`.

Comment: what's preventing you from trying this in the interpreter?

Comment: `w: Opens in write-only mode. The pointer is placed at the beginning of the file and this will overwrite any existing file with the same name. It will create a new file if one with the same name doesn't exist.` likely want `a: Opens a file for appending new information to it. The pointer is placed at the end of the file. A new file is created if one with the same name doesn't exist.`

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Trying this would be less painful than asking this here! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('file','w')
f.write('hi'+'\n')
f.close()
```

output: "hi" in file nothing else, this is because 'w' will overwrite the file causing it to be blank before entering the text,

```
f = open('file','a')
f.write('hi'+'\n')
f.close()
```

output *whatever's in text file to begin with* + "Hi", this will add the text to the file

```
f = open('file','r')
f.write('hi'+'\n')
f.close()
```

output error since you opened the file to read and therefore you cant add text